# OpenGL for Pygame in Python Error

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pygame

I am trying to learn 3d by following thenewboston on you tube. I got the

```
import OpenGL
```

to work, but then when he types in

```
from OpenGL.GLU import *
```

it does not work. I noticed that I had a folder named OpenGL inside the OpenGL folder. So I changed the one inside to GL. I typed in

```
from OpenGL.GL.GLU import *
```

and it still did not work. It is giving me this error.

```
File "C:\Python34\OpenGL\GL\__init__.py", line 174, in <module>
    from OpenGL.version import __version__
ImportError: No module named 'OpenGL.version'
```

I looked this up and on another thread here on stackoverflow, it said to use setup tools and enter the command directory of easyinstall. I have pip and setup tools installed along with opengl of course. I entered in my directery into cmd as

```
C:\Python34\setuptools\easy_install pyopengl
```

It then gave me this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\setuptools\eas
    from setuptools.command.easy_i
  File "C:\Python34\setuptools\set
    from six.moves import filter,
ImportError: No module named 'six'
```

Here is my code at the start.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import OpenGL
from OpenGL.GL.GLU import *
import pip
import setuptools
```

If anyone knows what I can do that would be very helpful. Thank you for your time and effort in solving this problem.

Edit 1:

I tried using pip and I got this error.

```
Command "C:\Python34\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:
ers\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-1nitmoob\\PyOpenGL-accelerate\\se
py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\
, '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Te
ip-_p9qo3yf-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --
ile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-
moob\PyOpenGL-accelerate
```

The video I am using is https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Snl7UwuMoD4&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGAjkwJocj7vlc_mFU-4wXJq&index=91

Comment: You're using Windows and Python 3.4, right? According to the [pyopengl homepage](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/) the easiest way to install it is to use pip. Open the command line and enter `py -3.4 -m pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate`. This will install pyopengl explicitly for Python 3.4 and runs pip as a module (to avoid PATH variable problems for Windows users). Also please add a link to the video.

Comment: I tried pip install using your command and got an error. I added that error and well as the link to the video at edit number 1.

Comment: No idea what's wrong. If `import OpenGL` works it should actually be installed, but maybe it was installed incorrectly. The "OpenGL" directory should be inside of the `C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages` directory and it looks like you have it in your Python34 directory. You could try to uninstall or delete all pyopengl related stuff in your Python folder and install it one more time or try a fresh Python (3.6) installation (you could also use a virtualenv if you know how that works). I've just installed only PyOpenGL via pip for Python 3.6 and `from OpenGL.GLU import *` works.

Comment: BTW, star imports are considered bad practise because they make code harder to read. If a module name is too long for your taste you can shorten it like so: `import pygame as pg`.

Comment: I looked at site packages folder and opengl was not there. So I copied opengl from the python folder somewhere and placed it in there. Same error still. I tried a clean install before btw, so that doesn't help it. I do not know how virtualenv works so it is either manually or pip install. I do have pip and setup tools. I said import setup tools and import pip and they both work. But opengl is the only one that don't work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: How did you actually install pyopengl the first time? Do you also have other Python versions installed? I'd try to install the newest Python version and `py -3.6 -m pip install PyOpenGL` again.

Comment: I had to use winrar on the file to extract it and I placed it in my python folder in my c drive. I tried the py -3.6 -m pip install PyOpenGL code thing again and did not work. I do not have other versions installed.

Comment: I actually works now. I changed the 3.6 number to 3.4 and it installed successfully. I tested and it worked. Thanks so much dude. If you could create a short answer, I can give you the correct answer thing if you want. Thanks again.

Comment: Oh that's cool, but I still wonder why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently `py -3.4 -m pip install PyOpenGL` works now, but we should still try to figure out why it didn't work before.

Users with other operating systems than Windows can just enter `pip install PyOpenGL` or `pip3 install PyOpenGL` (for Python 3). This also works on Windows, but the "/Scripts" folder has to be in the PATH.

Comment: I have no idea why it did not work before, but I think this thread offered a lot of different solutions to this problem and will help many people down the road like me. Thank you again and we can continue to try to understand why it did not work if you want. I upvoted yours and gave you the green check mark. Thank you again so much.

Comment: I guess the original error had to do with the fact that you had the OpenGL directory in another OpenGL directory and then Python couldn't find the module in the subdirectory. But then the error should've looked like this: `ImportError: No module named 'OpenGL.GLU'`. I'm really not sure about this and I also don't understand the cryptic error in your "Edit 1". Maybe someone else can figure this out.

Comment: Ya maybe someone else can figure it out. I am just glad it works now thanks to you. I think this thread will still help because in the future though as there we many different solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [six module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six), either pip or easy-install. Just keep installing whatever modules it says are missing until it works.

Comment: Ok, where do I install it because I downloaded the six module and I put it in many different locations and it still says no module named six. I even tried taking the six file from the six folder and placing it directly in the setup tools folder?